# How to open text file from two or more words named folder using batch?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have 2 files. `open.bat` & `file.txt`

I am trying to open `file.txt` from `open.bat`

The problem is, `file.txt` is located in `d:\Tom and Jerry\file.txt` this path, which name a folder named with three words `Tom and Jerry`

**The command i am running,**

```
start "d:\Tom and Jerry\file.txt"
```

**ERROR :**

> Instead opening the file.txt its Just Opening another command Window
>   named with file name and file path

**Expected :** Directly open `file.txt` from the path and `open.bat` should not run in background.

**Note :** `Call "d:\Tom and Jerry\file.txt"` This command line works. But, its running the cmd window in the background visually. So, i need the same solution using Start command line. Kindly Fix my code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put an extra `""` before:

`start "" "d:\Tom and Jerry\file.txt"`

or simply call it without `start`

`"d:\Tom and Jerry\file.txt"`

Comment: You should explain why you need the empty quotes ...

Comment: the 1st `""` is the title of the new commad prompt window that will be started. Type `start /?` for more information

Comment: I know. I meant you should add that explanation to your answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Any time a command doesn't do what you think it should the first thing you should do is [read the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start). The first sentence on that page tells you `start` “Starts a separate Command Prompt window”, and that is exactly what it is doing.

If you want to open a file from a batch command just put the name of the file in the batch command:

```
"d:\Tom and Jerry\file.txt"
```

That opens the file using the default app for the file extension. If that's not what you want you have to explain what to “directly open a file” means.